# Implement string to sqlite3 DB query

Tags: python

I have many tables filled with rows and I want to be able to pass in input strings as variables to the query, I have tried many things and research but can't figure it out. Here is the code

```
def find_model(model,name):
    c.execute('''SELECT ? FROM ?''')#,(model,name)
    rows = c.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
           print(row)
find_model(2610-48,2610-48)
```

Comment: Did you try f strings? As in
def find_model(model, name):
    c.execute(f"SELECT {model} FROM {name}"),

Comment: SQLite does not allow parameters for column or table names.

Answer (score 0):

qmark (?) style queries only supported for parameters but not for table name or column list.

For substituting column list or table name you can use all formatting related features, for example:

- f string - `f"select {columns} from {table}"` where **columns** and **table** are vaiables in current scope
- % string formatting - `"select %s from %s" % ("a,b,c", "super_table")`

But never use anything from this features for parameters in update/create queries, specially for user-passed data. Always use qmark syntax to ensure no sql injections can be performed. For example: `cur.execute("insert into test values (?, ?)", ("a", 123))`([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute)).

Quick summary:

- never substitute untrusted user input via string formatting to query
- you can substitute columns and table names to query using formatting features of python, but do this only for trusted input values
- always use qmark style queries form parameters